# md5 of MySQL result

Tags: mysql, md5

I want to get md5 hash value of mysql result without using php to it. Is it possible?

This query results in error:

```
SELECT md5(*) FROM bookings WHERE dep_id = 1;
```

Because md5 expects string as parameter - 
How can I send the whole result into md5 function?

[EDIT]
I can't hardcode every single column name in the query because of - there is around 100 columns, besides their names/amount changes often.

Comment: Concatenate every column into a string and hash that.

Comment: But what if number of columns is unknown?

Comment: In SQL, number of columns (and their names) is always known. If it's unknown, then you are using SQL wrong (no, SQL is not a big text file).

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate all fields usding `CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT md5(CONCAT(field1,field2,field3 ...)) FROM bookings WHERE dep_id = 1;
```

Comment: But what if number of columns is unknown? Or there is around 100 columns ?

Comment: Number of columns is known in SQL DB by definition. And what changes if there are 100 columns? Only length of the query.

Comment: The good question is: Are the result of the following expressions equal: `MD5(CONCAT('a',NULL,'b'))` and `MD5(CONCAT('a','','b'))`. And what about these: `MD5(CONCAT('12','34'))` and `MD5(CONCAT('1','234'))`

Comment: The thing is I can't change this query every time a new column popups -  I need a dynamic query - otherwise I will have to do it with PHP.

Comment: Then do it in PHP. It will be much easier. Anyway, as N.B. mentioned in his comment under you question, it seems that you've made some mistakes designing your application and you're using RDBMS in a wrong way.

Comment: Do it with PHP and respect NULLs, column data types, separate columns properly. In SQL there is no concept for dynamic column list. (Yes, you can build a sql string dynamically, but the column count in the query is static).